# Calculate time in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using sql server to store employee lunch in and out time and calculating difference using asp.net as below. Now i want to see if they exceed 30 mins then value should be in red color.

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //Lunch Total Time
    Label lunIn = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLunIn");
    Label lunOut = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLunOut");
    Label lunTotal = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLunTotal");
    lunTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToDateTime(lunOut.Text) - Convert.ToDateTime(lunIn.Text));
}
```

How should i go about it? Thanks

Comment: In which country are you working?

Comment: I was just interested because that sounds more like china or north korea. However, what is the problem, that you don't know how to get the total time? Use the datasource instead of thegridviewrows.

Comment: look into the `System.TimeSpan` class.

Comment: I got the total time but wanted to know from here.. how can i make it in red if 'lunTotal' is greater than 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

In general i would prefer to use the real data-source instead of the text in the `GridViewRows`. You can get it easily in `RowDataBound` via `e.Row.DataItem`. On that way you prevent localization issues and your work with the original data.

However, to get the time in minutes from two `DateTime`s you can subtract them and use the returned `TimeSpan`s `TotalMinutes` property:

```
DateTime dtIn = Convert.ToDateTime(lunIn.Text);
DateTime dtOut = Convert.ToDateTime(lunOut.Text);
TimeSpan duration = dtOut - dtin;
lunTotal.Text = duration.ToString();
if(duration.TotalMinutes > 30)
{
    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red;
    // or maybe you just want to change the color of the Label
    lunTotal.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
```